# Unable to display the content of {% block content %}{% endblock %} in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, tags

I can't display the content of {% block content %}{% endblock %} on my web page.

Here is the tree structure:

- toolbox/

  - toolbox/

    - lisa/

      - templates/

        - lisa/

          - lisa.html
    - templates/

      - base.html

Here is the code of base.html :

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="main-content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code of lisa.html:

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Bienvenue !</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rhoncus 
        massa non tortor. Vestibulum diam diam, posuere in viverra in, 
        ullamcorper et libero. Donec eget libero quis risus congue imperdiet ac 
        id lectus. Nam euismod cursus arcu, et consequat libero ullamcorper sit 
        amet.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Do you know where it could have come from?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Almost certainly, your view is rendering the parent not the child; otherwise you'd get the TemplateNotFound exception for your extends block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Priyanshu Gupta
Thank you for your answer, looking at my tree structure is similar to the one you gave me.
So here is the "template" part that I have in my "setting.py" file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # Cette ligne ajoute le dossier templates/ à la racine du projet
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Remove the `'DIRS':[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`. Instead, it should be just `'DIRS':['templates']`.

Comment: This answer should have been an update to the question.

Comment: I changed the"'DIRS':[os.path.join (BASE_DIR, "templates'),]" to"'DIRS': ['templates']," however I still can't display the content of my lisa.html

Comment: I found the solution, I had put "base.html" in "views.py", whereas I had to put "lisa/lisa.html"

Answer (score 1):

Your project structure should look like this:

```
toolbox
├── lisa
│   ├── templates
|   |   └── lisa
│   │       └── lisa.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── templates
│   └── base.html
├── toolbox
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

In your settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

1. I am assuming that in your settings.py you have set template directory as 
   `templates`.
2. In lisa.html just write `{% extends 'base.html' %}`. By doing this Django searches for `templates/base.html` which exists, hence it should work.
3. The reason behind your code not working is when you are writing `{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}`, Django searches for `templates/templates/base.html` which actually doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}
```

To:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Comment: I just modified it and it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try a double check on the url in the urls.py forder like for instance if it's like that :
 EX:

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home,),
        path('lisa', views.lisa,),
```

2.Then it won't work on the url: http://localhost:8000/
you have to double check that it is :http://localhost:8000/lisa